# Do all developer orgs come with a bunch of custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, fields, developer-edition

I previously installed an app from AppEchange to my developer org, and after a while, uninstalled it. I now have no installed packages. I recently noticed that the standard Account Edit page is using a bunch of custom fields such as "SLA", "Customer Priority", "Number of Locations", and "Active".

It seems odd that the vanilla version would come with custom fields. Are these left over from that App, or these some kind of oxymoronic standard custom fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few different Developer Edition templates floating about, and which one you'll get is determined by the link you used to access the Developer Edition sign up page. The usual one, found on developer.force.com, will always come with the same custom fields, classes, and so on. Every once in a while, special templates are distributed to showcase a new feature, like the Lightning Developer Edition, which came pre-bundled with a couple of Lightning Components and a different set of Apex Classes used by those components.

There's one default template that's applied by default to all new trial editions and developer editions, *except* for those created by TrialForce, created by an ISV partner through the Partner Portal, or that come from a special sign up page (as mentioned above). If you're not from an ISV, and not using a TrialForce edition, and not using a special sign up page, you can count on these fields being present.

This includes some awfully industry specific fields, products, and so on, such as the GenWatt products, the "Current Generators" field on opportunities, as well as a bunch of other generic fields, like "SLA" and "Customer Priority." The only way to fix this is to manually clean up this data.

Each new org will come with the following:

- About 25 Custom Lead, Contact, Case, Opportunity, and Account fields.
- About 17 Products
- A Custom Price Book
- Apex Classes
- Apex Pages
- About 12 Accounts
- About 25 Contacts
- About 30 Opportunities
- About 26 Cases
- About 10 Solutions
- About 15 Leads
- About 4 Campaigns

The exact number may vary, as this data is coming from my Lightning Developer Edition rather than a normal Developer Edition (all of my normal ones have been modified/cleaned up), but this should give you a general feel for how much clean up you'll have to go through.

It should take you probably less than an hour for your first time, and once you get used to the process, it should take quite a bit less. I usually have everything cleaned up in about 5 or 10 minutes.