# Standard custom fields

Tags: custom-field, package

I have a totally new, untouched org (Partner Developer Edition). I was going to make some customizations but before I did I created a new unmanaged package. I happen to notice though that there are already some custom fields that I didn't create (see image below). What are these? Some kind of custom field that come bundled into every org?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Depending upon type of org you signed up they come with variety of preloaded metadata(custom fields, profiles , roles etc..). Typically you go through clean up post creation of the developer org.

To give you more detailed information on types of pre-bundles metadata and how to clean them up below are some resources.

1. [Do all developer orgs come with a bunch of custom fields?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76226/do-all-developer-orgs-come-with-a-bunch-of-custom-fields)
2. [Preparing and Cleaning new Salesforce Developer Orgs](https://www.altify.com/blog/part-ii-preparing-cleaning-new-developer-orgs/)

Also like @David Reed  mentioned in the comment you can leverage sratch orgs as they do not come with anything preloaded.

**Scratch Orgs:** The [scratch org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) is a source-driven and disposable deployment of Salesforce code and metadata. A scratch org is fully configurable, allowing developers to emulate different Salesforce editions with different features and preferences. You can share the scratch org configuration file with other team members, so you all have the same basic org in which to do your development.

[Supported Scratch Org Editions for Partners](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/isv_partner_scratch_org_editions.htm)

Comment: n.b. this is configurable for scratch orgs - they by default do *not* come with anything preloaded, but you can turn on sample data and metadata in the scratch definition file with the `hasSampleData` key.

Comment: @DavidReed True. I didn't think of scratch orgs!